# Exception on @RequestParam annotation used from statefulJ framework

Tags: java, spring-mvc, servlets

I'm getting an exception like below when I try to get parameter from http request using spring(@RequestParam):

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:973)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)


root cause
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
org.statefulj.framework.core.actions.MethodInvocationAction.execute(MethodInvocationAction.java:120)
org.statefulj.fsm.FSM.executeAction(FSM.java:228)
org.statefulj.framework.core.fsm.FSM.transition(FSM.java:110)
org.statefulj.fsm.FSM.onEvent(FSM.java:116)
org.statefulj.framework.core.fsm.FSM.onEvent(FSM.java:87)
org.statefulj.framework.core.model.impl.StatefulFSMImpl.onEvent(StatefulFSMImpl.java:74)
org.statefulj.framework.core.model.impl.FSMHarnessImpl.onEvent(FSMHarnessImpl.java:85)
org.statefulj.framework.persistence.jpa.JPAFSMHarnessImpl.access$001(JPAFSMHarnessImpl.java:30)
org.statefulj.framework.persistence.jpa.JPAFSMHarnessImpl$1.doInTransaction(JPAFSMHarnessImpl.java:52)
org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:131)
org.statefulj.framework.persistence.jpa.JPAFSMHarnessImpl.onEvent(JPAFSMHarnessImpl.java:47)
statefulj.controller.StatefulJControllerMVCBinder.$_get_(StatefulJControllerMVCBinder.java)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:175)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:446)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:434)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)


root cause
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
org.statefulj.framework.core.actions.MethodInvocationAction.invoke(MethodInvocationAction.java:149)
org.statefulj.framework.core.actions.MethodInvocationAction.invoke(MethodInvocationAction.java:139)
org.statefulj.framework.core.actions.MethodInvocationAction.execute(MethodInvocationAction.java:98)
org.statefulj.fsm.FSM.executeAction(FSM.java:228)
org.statefulj.framework.core.fsm.FSM.transition(FSM.java:110)
org.statefulj.fsm.FSM.onEvent(FSM.java:116)
org.statefulj.framework.core.fsm.FSM.onEvent(FSM.java:87)
org.statefulj.framework.core.model.impl.StatefulFSMImpl.onEvent(StatefulFSMImpl.java:74)
org.statefulj.framework.core.model.impl.FSMHarnessImpl.onEvent(FSMHarnessImpl.java:85)
org.statefulj.framework.persistence.jpa.JPAFSMHarnessImpl.access$001(JPAFSMHarnessImpl.java:30)
org.statefulj.framework.persistence.jpa.JPAFSMHarnessImpl$1.doInTransaction(JPAFSMHarnessImpl.java:52)
org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:131)
org.statefulj.framework.persistence.jpa.JPAFSMHarnessImpl.onEvent(JPAFSMHarnessImpl.java:47)
statefulj.controller.StatefulJControllerMVCBinder.$_get_(StatefulJControllerMVCBinder.java)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:175)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:446)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:434)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

But the thing is that I use @StatefulController and statefulJ framework(http://www.statefulj.org/). When I use @RequestParam with @Controller annotation it works but in @StatefulController I'm getting exception. According to the official demo(https://github.com/statefulj/statefulj-framework-demo-mongo/blob/master/src/main/java/org/statefulj/webapp/controller/UserController.java) this annotation should work in @StatefulController.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Here is my code:

```
@StatefulController(
    clazz=Reservation.class,
    startState=Reservation.FREE,
    factoryId="reservationFactory")
public class StatefulJController
{
  public static final String HOMEPAGE_EVENT = "springmvc:/";
  public static final String RESERVE_EVENT = "springmvc:/reserve";

  @Transition(event=RESERVE_EVENT)
  public String startReservation(@RequestParam String quantity)
  {
    System.out.println(quantity);
    return "reserve";
  }
}
```

Comment: Is the parameter `quantity` actually available for the method? Does it work if you put `@RequestParam(required=false)`?

Comment: What do you mean by availible? The exception occours when the variable is beeing obtained so when I call request like that:
http://localhost:8080/FMS/reserve?quantity=12
required=false doesn't help

Comment: There's clearly an error in the reflection call. Does it work if you change quantity from `String` to `int`? Either the type(s) or the amounts of the arguments are preventing the call from succeeding.

Comment: Yes, I tried with different types. It's the same for int or Integer type.

Answer (score 1):

StatefulJ always passes in the Entity and Event on the first two parameters.

From the documentation: http://www.statefulj.org/framework/#define-your-transitions

> When a Transition is invoked, the StatefulJ Framework will call the associated method.
> If the StatefulController is a Controller (vs a Domain Entity), then the first two parameters of the method are always:
>
> Stateful Entity
>
> The Event

So your method should look like:

```
public String startReservation(Reservation reservation, String event, @RequestParam String quantity)
```

Comment: Thank you. I noticed that after I posted :) Now it works